# Coffeescript, how do I pass variables in a function in this case?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm new to coffeescript and I'm stuck in a easy problem that I feel ashamed :S ...

How would you pass the variable `query` inside the function?

```
query = 'select * from blabla'
pg.connect conString, (err, client, done) ->
            client.query query, (err, result) ->
                    if err
                        console.log "error"
                    else
                        console.log "success"
                    done()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pass inside"? Pass inside to what? The callback? It's already visible there because it's in lexical scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.
The real problem was probably that the name `query` was too generic :/
Solved with changing the name of the variable..

```
theQuery = 'select * from blabla'
pg.connect conString, (err, client, done) ->
            client.query theQuery, (err, result) ->
                    if err
                        console.log "error"
                    else
                        console.log "success"
                    done()
```

Comment: I don't understand why changing this variable name would affect anything.

Comment: It solved the problem. I think that it might have been already used or "query" special naming.

Comment: coffeescript hides the hoisting, hence, local variables overwrite global ones. You need to be more careful about variable naming in coffeescript than in javascript, especially as you have no means to see that you actually overwrite a global variable. see http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope for more details